# ServiceStack ORM Lite Left Join query filter

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I am not able to filter out the records correctly.

```
q = q.LeftJoin<PurchaseInvoice, PurchaseInvoiceProjectLink>((pi, pipl) => pi.Id == pipl.PurchaseInvoiceId);
q = q.Where<PurchaseInvoiceProjectLink>(s => Sql.In(s.ProjectId, UserSession.ProjectIds)) || s == null );
```

The `s == null` part does not work and I see it is materialised in the sql query into  `OR ('{}' is null))`

I am not sure if it is a bug in Servicestack ORM Lite or the code should be written in other way.

====

OK. I haved resolved this as below (but still looking something to not use pragma.

```
#pragma warning disable CS0472 // The result of the expression is always the same since a value of this type is never equal to 'null'
            q = q.Where<PurchaseInvoiceProjectLink>(s => ... ||  s.PurchaseInvoiceId == null);
#pragma warning restore CS0472 // The result of the expression is always the same since a value of this type is never equal to 'null'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
q = q.LeftJoin<PurchaseInvoice, PurchaseInvoiceProjectLink>((pi, pipl) => pi.Id == pipl.PurchaseInvoiceId).Where<PurchaseInvoiceProjectLink>(s => s.Id == null || UserSession.ProjectIds.Contains(s.ProjectId));
```

Comment: I already given the solution. Still looking for other method to avoid using pragma CD0472

Comment: So use a nullable string property which should be mandatory in the database

Comment: @labibe On database layer the PurchaseInvoiceProjectLink.PurchaseInvoiceId must not be null

Comment: @marcinn it is mapped as "int" so you'll still have the warning.

Comment: @labibe that is correct I, when doing left join I need to compare non nullable int with null to produce correct sql statement using ORM lite.